# Android install apk on phone

Tags: android

I have a game I built in eclipse and now want to install on my phone.

I downloaded ASTRO per an example in YouTube, then copied the .apk file to the SD Card, went to the phone, found it try to install it but it seems like it doesn't recognize it because it does not give me the option to install although I can browse through my assets, drawables etc...

Am I missing something? I just want to download it to the phone ... but all I see is a black list under summary with no description and no button to click on for "Install".

Comment: I don't know about eclipse, but with intelliJ, if you don't have an emulator running, it will try to run the app on a connected device, see if you can find a similar option in eclipse so you don't have to keep copying files / running shell commands

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try installing it via adb. Type
`'the path to your adb on the pc - it's located in the platform-tools directory of the sdk' install 'the path to your apk on the pc'` 
in the shell. i.e
`adb install myapp.apk` in case the path to your adb installation is in the system path and your current directory is the one with the apk.

Comment: Thank you, I am having trouble finding the command prompt for adb

Comment: just start the standard shell. If you're using windows - just hit the windows key>run>cmd and navigate to the folder containing you adb install - it's usually C://Program Files/User/Android/android-sdk/platform-tools or if you're running on Linux just start the terminal and yet again navigate to you adb directory (usually ~/Android/android-sdk-linux_x86/platform-tools/ and then type adb install 'the path to your .apk file on the pc'

Comment: I develop with eclipse and a emulator... I do not see the sdk in my file hirarchy, i was able to acees this though

C:\Users\name\.android\avd\MyVirtualDevice.avd ... but i think i am in the wrong place... Sorry I am new to this

Comment: So you're tring to upload you application to an emulator, but not to an actual phone(device)? If so then when you run you app in eclipse it will get automatically uploaded to the emulator and it will get started. Btw, this actually happens when you have connected a real device as well. You upload something through adb more like when you don't have the code/can't run it in eclipse. Dunno why I suggested you go with the adb, duh!

Comment: No, I am trying to do it to the phone now.. i was just seeiing if i could access the path you mentioned which i dont see

Comment: Ok. So you shouldn't be looking for files starting with an . as those are hidden files. Try using the windows search to find Android or android-sdk or platform-tools or adb. Other way to locate your sdk is to click on window > preferences>android in eclipse. There you should be able to find the path to your sdk. Besided when hit ctrl+F11 in eclipse doesn't it suggest you to run the app on the device? If it doesn't are you sure that windows finds the device(or you should install some drivers beforehand)?

Comment: Hi, I found the adb but everytime i try to open it it runs and closes before i could do anything :(

Comment: don't try to open it directly. Open start>run>cmd and navigate to the directory containing it.(type cd 'the path to the directory containing the adb') Now type adb install 'the path to the apk file'.

Comment: something like adb install G:\myapk.apk

Answer (score 1):

If you develop i think you got android sdk set up, try to fire up install from the command line by using : adb install 
Make sure adb is in your path and your phone has development settings turned on.

Comment: Thank you, I am having trouble finding the command prompt for adb

Comment: It got moved, into platform-tools I believe.

Comment: Yes, it is under your SDK dir in platform-tools.

Answer (score 1):

you can also open it using the webrowser 
using file:///sdcard/bla.apk

Answer (score 1):

If you can browse your assets etc then it sounds like you used long-press in Astro and then told it to 'Extract'. This doesn't install the app, it simply unpacks the apk into its component parts.

Do a 'short-press' (click) on the apk file with Astro and it should give you the option to 'Open App Manager'. This should allow you to install it.

Comment: I did this and did not provide me with the option to install

Comment: @user710502: Edit your question and post your AndroidManifest.xml file

Answer (score 1):

I had this happen to me and this is what I had to do to fix it. Since the option to install is grayed out you need to edit your AndroidManifest.xml and tell Android what sdk version it targets. The version on your phone is probably 2.1 and you have been developing on 2.2. This is what you need to insert into the manifest file.

```
<uses-sdk 
android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="8" android:maxSdkVersion="8">
</uses-sdk>
```

Answer (score 0):

Renaming the .apk to some other extension is not enough to enable beaming.  Android will look into the file.  You must rename the file then zip it.  After that a beam will work and just reverse the process before installing on the device.

This is quite a pain because I beam my apk hundreds of times while testing.  On my desire with froyo it was allowed but now on my nexus s with gingerbread it is blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out you can email the apk to your gmail account as an attatchment and you can install the apk straight from the email. When you open up the email scroll to the very botton and you will see a "Install" button.  it's a quick and easy solution.

Comment: Quick and easy?! Not compared to installing via adb. Eclipse will transfer it and run it for you with one button press!